# How can I add points to a vector of a struct type

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to add points(vertices) to a vector of struct type. I am a beginner and I know I can use push_back. But I keep getting three errors:

- no appropriate default constructor available
- left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union
- expression must have class type.

What I am doing wrong?
Here's my code...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct Points
{
    int x, y;
    Points(int paramx, int paramy) : x(paramx), y(paramy) {}  
}p1,p2;

vector <Points> pointes();

void addPoint(int a, int b);
void directionPoint(Points p1, Points p2);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

void addPoint(int x, int y)
{
    pointes.push_back(Points(x, y));    
}

void directionPoint(Points p1, Points p2)
{  
    if ((p1.x*p2.y - p2.x*p1.y) > 0)
    {
        cout << "direction is anticlockwise" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "direction is clockwise" << endl;
}
```

Comment: As written, `pointes` is a function taking no parameters and returning `vector<Points>`. Drop the pair of parentheses in its declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **no appropriate default constructor available** is caused by your code

```
} p1,p2;
```

This can be corrected by either creating an appropriate constructor in your struct, removing these values if not needed, or using the existing constructor:

```
} p1(0,0),p2(0,0);
```

The **left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union and expression must have class type** error is caused by

```
vector <Points> pointes();
```

To correct it remove the parenthesis:

```
vector <Points> pointes;
```

Comment: Thanks loads for the answers, really helpful

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` doesn't require its value type to be default-constructible. The reasons for compile errors are different:

```
struct Points
{
  //...
}p1,p2;
```

You declare `p1` and `p2` with no arguments. To do that `struct Points` must have a default constructor. You have to either remove them or specify arguments for the constructor.

Also,

```
vector <Points> pointes();
```

This declares a function `pointes` taking no arguments and returning `vector<Points>`. Declare it just as `vector <Points> pointes;`

After these two changes the code compiles: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a07f08cd8009c996)

Comment: Thanks :) now understand things much better